# Powershell, help read log file to get specific keywords

Tags: regex, powershell

How to read a log file to get keyword *fail* and timestamp from date then print it to csv?

example: I have a file test.txt which contains

```
20160201-00:00:00 Success ..
20160201-11:11:11 Fail..
```

I want a report showing for all fails

```
Date          Time       Result
----------
20160201      11:11:11   Fail
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried, then we are more than happy to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to read the text file using the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet. To parse the Logs, you could use the following Regex ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG2pV2/1)):

```
(\d{8})-(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\w+)
```

In the following example, I iterate over the matches using the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet (alias `%`) and create a new Object with the desired properties. 
To filter only the `Fail` Reports, you can use the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet (alias `Where`).
To convert the Object to a CSV, you can use the [Export-CSV](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$content = Get-Content 'C:\Yourpathto\test.txt'
$regex = '(\d{8})-(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(\w+)'
[regex]::Matches($content, $regex) | % {  
    [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date = $_.Groups.Value[1]
            Time = $_.Groups.Value[2]
            Result = $_.Groups.Value[3]
            }
 } | Where Result -eq 'Fail' | Export-Csv -Path c:\test.csv
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting empty file. Just to make it easy here is what I have in the test.txt. 20160401-01:10:00 SUCCESS 
20160401-01:10:00 Fail
20160401-01:10:00 SUCCESS 
20160401-01:10:00 Fail 
…

Comment: this works for me, I get the desired output..Did you received any error?

Comment: Thanks! It works I was having issues with Regex. :) appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
(gc log.txt) -match 'fail' | % { 
    $_ -match '^([^ ]+ )(.+)'
    $matches[1] + ',' $matches[2] | out-file -Append out.csv
}
```

This is very close to what you want, you just need to polish it a bit.

Comment: The OP should show at least show _some effort_ before we answer. There is probably a dupe close to that title alone which might actually help. This reads like a gimme the codes question. If the user is indeed new you should avoid using aliases when try to show people what to do. You also don't explain how any of this works.

Comment: If he is new, its better to use aliases then no aliases. Posh aliases are not random words but have a history in linux world, the probability is higher that he will know about `ls` for example then `get-childitem`. The OP also should know how to read code, otherwise its pointless. I don't want to explain trivial code.